# Visual Studio 2010 Sku upgrade. From Professional to Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional (final version), with some components, plug-ins and templates I use a lot. Recently, I been checking all the things that the Ultimate version has, and I've been wondering,

Can I just run the VS2010 ultimate installer and it upgrade the Sku, letting me use all of its features along with the previous plug-ins (like telerik rad controls, Deklarit for VS2010, and VS.php)??

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's been an hour, plenty of time to uninstall Prof.  Which I'd recommend, little point here in testing if they got it right.

Comment: Good Point. Doing it right now for testing and I'll share what went wrong (if is the case)

Comment: Are you sure that your credit cards are not charged?

Comment: @chandhu this question was about upgrading the SKU and was asking for the technical aspect. Since I have a MSDN and it also incluides VS Ultimate, just wanted to know if it was available. And Off course, it was not charged per my change.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just for records, looks like everything worked pretty well.... And the answer to my own question is: Yes, you can Upgrade the Sku of Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Works well indeed, the update was done in maybe 10 minutes. The installer told me that .net, VS2010 Pro and other things were already installed and that it would only install Ultimate.

Answer (score 7):

Just to confirm that the upgrade path worked for me:

I simply ran the setup program for Ultimate without uninstalling Professional. It installed in less than an hour taking with it all of my settings, plugins and extentions & resharper came across also :)

Very Impressed ! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it works, I also upgraded Professional to Ultimate. Have to mention, that while updating I was not able to change the path for additional components. But ugrade works.